# Facebook graph api to get recent feed's by other user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i want to get particular person public feeds to show in my application.but in response empty data value returning.without login into Facebook i have get the Facebook user public post.
Am getting response: Unsupported get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible, you can only get access to the feed (public or not) of someone who authorized your App with the `user_posts` permission. You could use an Extended User Token that is valid for 60 days to read the feed, but in general you are not supposed to show user feeds on an external website. Better use a Page for that, with an App Token or Extended Page Token - both are valid forever.